# Express a large intersection in terms of smaller ones

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to work on a problem the aim of which is to express the size of an intersection of $n$ sets in terms of merely 1-wise and 2-wise intersections. The setup is as follows:

> Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let $\pi=(\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n)$ be a target subsequence of $n$ events, where each $\pi_i$ takes values in $E=\{e_1,\ldots,e_m\}$. Consider a stream $\sigma$ from which we collect each possible contiguous subsequence of $n$ events that we shall compare to the target one. Write $X_{\pi}^{(i)}$ as the set of each subsequence in which the $i$'th event is identical to the $i$'th in $\pi$. Moreover, define the following quantities:
> $$X_1:=\sum_{j\in[n]}|X_{\pi}^{(j)}|,\quad X_2:=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}|X_{\pi}^{(i)}\cap X_{\pi}^{(j)}|,\quad\ldots,\quad X_n:=\left|\bigcap_{j\in[n]}X_{\pi}^{(j)}\right|.$$

From the inclusion-exclusion principle, we know that
\begin{align*}
\left|\bigcup_{j\in[n]}X_{\pi}^{(j)}\right|&=X_1-X_2+\ldots+(-1)^{n-2}X_{n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}X_n\\
&=\sum_{k\in[n]}(-1)^{k-1}X_k.
\end{align*}
This gives the following expression for the $n$-wise intersection:
$$X_n=(-1)^{n-1}\left(\sum_{k\in[n-1]}(-1)^kX_k+\left|\bigcup_{j\in[n]}X_{\pi}^{(j)}\right|\right)$$

What I would like to do, is express $X_n$ in terms of $X_1$ and $X_2$ only, since we are only given access to exact values of each 1-wise and 2-wise intersections, but not larger ones. I am aware that it will not be possible to have exact values. In our case, lower and upper bounds are sufficient. Until now, I have been helping myself with Bonferonni inequalities (see [Bonferonni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_inequality#Bonferroni_inequalities)) which I thought were good enough, but it turns out the bounds are rather relaxed.

The value of $X_n$, I express as
\begin{align*}
  X_n=\begin{cases}
    \sum_{j\in[n-1]}(-1)^jX_j+|\cup_{j\in[n]}X_{\pi}^{(j)}|,&\text{ for $n$ odd}\\
    \sum_{j\in[n-1]}(-1)^{j-1}X_j-|\cup_{j\in[n]}X_{\pi}^{(j)}|,&\text{ for $n$ even}.
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
where the union adheres to the bounds:
\begin{align*}
  \left|\bigcup_{j\in[n]}X_{\pi}^{(j)}\right|\leq
  \begin{cases}
    \sum_{j\in[n-2]}(-1)^{j-1}X_j,&\text{ for $n$ odd}\\
    \sum_{j\in[n-1]}(-1)^{j-1}X_j,&\text{ for $n$ even},
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  \left|\bigcup_{j\in[n]}X_{\pi}^{(j)}\right|\geq
  \begin{cases}
    \sum_{j\in[n-1]}(-1)^{j-1}X_j,&\text{ for $n$ odd}\\
    \sum_{j\in[n-2]}(-1)^{j-1}X_j,&\text{ for $n$ even}.
  \end{cases}
\end{align*}

This however gives me basically that $0\leq X_n\leq X_{n-1}\leq\ldots\leq X_1$, which is not good enough for us (especially the lower bound which is, let's say, quite trivial).

Overall what I'm doing currently is somewhat using the inclusion-exclusion principle recursively for the expression of large intersections, along with the Bonferonni inequalities to get rid of the union I cannot compute. I have also thought of considering the union as the complement of the intersection of the complements, in which case I could also apply the inclusion-exclusion principle recursively (since I can have access to the complements of the sizes of the small intersections) but it didn't go anywhere yet.

The best bounds that we have for now, is through the recursive computation of the minimum of smaller intersections. Namely, $$X_k\leq\min_{S\subseteq[n]:|S|=k-1}X_S,$$ for every $2\leq k\leq n$. I would thus highly appreciate if anyone had an idea on better methods I could use to find good bounds for this, or tell me maybe if I'm going in the wrong direction.